# How do Firebase rules functions with multi criteria work?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am having trouble understanding when to add an argument to the Firebase rule function. Currently, I am working on a general function that checks three criteria:

1. not null
2. own data
3. email verified

**this function will be used under all paths**

I don't want to create three separate functions since I am cracking down on clutter in my rules file, for this.

My main issue is that I am lacking an understanding are:

1. If I call the function under "match," will it have access to the
   global scope and therefore have access to the wildcard and request
   objects?
2. Should I return with parentheses () if there are more criteria, or
   should I simply return the criteria directly without parentheses?

Could give me some rules o thumb regarding to issues to solidify my understanding ?

**> return (requestAuth != null &&
requestAuth.uid == userId &&
requestAuth.token.email_verified)**

```js
//when this function have access to the request object ?
function allowCrudIfAuth() {
let requestAuth = request.auth;
return (requestAuth != null && // Authorized user. 
requestAuth.uid == userId && // Doc's owner.
requestAuth.token.email_verified) // Email must be verified.
}

// Match doc // Match doc data-users-session
match /data-users-sessions/{userId} { 
allow get: 
if allowCrudIfAuth()
allow create:
if allowCrudIfAuth()
allow update:
if allowCrudIfAuth() 
allow delete:
if allowCrudIfAuth() 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following function model seems to make things work. I commented the solution and the (rules of thumb) for a stable implementation across all security rules files, therefore now I can use this function all over the rules file.

```js
// Important:
// must pass the (request and the userId) as arguments to the function to work properly. 
// return the criteria directly without ().

function allowIfAuthed(request,userId) {
return request.auth != null && // Authorized user. 
request.auth.uid == userId && // Doc's owner.
request.auth.token.email_verified // Email must be verified
}
```